# Can not run-as my package to see the database

Tags: android, adb, samsung-mobile

I have an installed an app that has a db and I want to check the db.
I know the package name: `com.jim.app`
If I do:

```
$ adb shell  
shell@klte:/ $ run-as com.jim.app
run-as: Package 'com.jim.app' is unknown
```

But I know the app is installed and I can see the package name listed.

```
adb shell pm list packages |grep jim
package:com.jim.app
```

What is going on here?

Comment: for `run-as` to work the package has to be `debuggable`